# outlook 2010 automatic spellchecking fail

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, autocorrect

My Emails sometimes stop correcting misspelled words.  I can resolve the issue by going to

```
File | Options |  Mail (Left Tab) | Spelling and Auto Correct
```

I uncheck "Check spelling as you type", click OK out of all the dialog boxes to apply the change, go through again, and readd the check-mark.  This immediately resolves the issue.

This is crazy, why do I have to do this every other day, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your Add-Ins under word options:

[image]

[image]

Choose Disabled Items from the Manage drop down menu at the bottom. Then click the Go button. Make sure that Proofing is not disabled